# Core Data two degrees relationships bindings in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data model made like this :

**Persons <->> Jobs <<-> Society**

A Person can have multiple Jobs, each one in a different Society. 
Societies can have multiple Jobs.
Jobs can be related only to one Person and one Society.

Here is the picture of the Core Data Model :

[image: Relationships]

**I want to be able to put the Job and a NSComboBox containing all my Societies, with the good one selected, in a NSTableView (View based).** Here is the picture of my cell when one Person is selected :

[image: ComboBox]

For the moment I manage to bind the Person to their Jobs, and to get the Society related to the Job, but I'd like to **get the whole Societies NSArrayController objects and select the one related to the specific job**...

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you're looking to do, but here if you're just trying to select the right society cell based on a job, this is what you could do:

- To get all of the Societies, you should just make a fetchRequest without a predicate, e.g.:

  ```
  NSArray *societies = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Society"] error:&error];
  ```
- To select the right Society, you can just do a comparison in the tableViewCell by comparing job.society and the cell's society, or you could check to see whether the job is in the society.jobs set

There may be a way to do all of this by finding a count with a subquery in one fetch, but if that is even possible it's going to be a hard fetch to write.  It's also unnecessary by the sound of it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for your answer. The problem is that I'd like to do all this in IB. Actually I'm binding the popup to a SocietiesArrayController to get all the societies, but as **it works outside of the table view's cell** it doesn't when it's in...